# Paying the Minimum

Tags: python

I seem to be stuck on this question in MIT 6.00SC course.  I am very new to programming.

Question: Problem 1
Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the
minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.
Use raw_input() to ask for the following three floating point numbers:

1. the outstanding balance on the credit card
2. annual interest rate
3. minimum monthly payment rate

For each month, print the minimum monthly payment, remaining balance, principle paid in the
format shown in the test cases below. All numbers should be rounded to the nearest penny.
Finally, print the result, which should include the total amount paid that year and the remaining
balance.

Here is my new code:

```
outstand_balance = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:'))
ann_interest_rt = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:'))
min_month_rt = float(raw_input('Enter the minimum monthly payment as a decimal:'))
Month = int(1)
for month in range (0,12):
    Min_monthly_payment = round((min_month_rt * outstand_balance), 2)
    Interest_paid = round((ann_interest_rt/12 * outstand_balance), 2)
    Principle_paid = round((Min_monthly_payment - Interest_paid), 2)
    outstand_balance = round((outstand_balance - Min_monthly_payment), 2)
    Remaining_balance = round((outstand_balance - Min_monthly_payment) * (1 \+(ann_interest_rt/12)), 2)
    Month +=1
    print "Minmimum monthly payment $" + str(Min_monthly_payment)
    print "Principle Paid $" + str(Principle_paid)
    print "Remaining Balance $" + str(Remaining_balance)
    print "Month: " + str(Month)
```

It results in this:

```
    Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:4800
Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:.2
Enter the minimum monthly payment as a decimal:.02
Minmimum monthly payment $96.0
Principle Paid $16.0
Remaining Balance $4684.8
Month: 2
Minmimum monthly payment $94.08
Principle Paid $15.68
Remaining Balance $4591.1
Month: 3
Minmimum monthly payment $92.2
Principle Paid $15.37
Remaining Balance $4499.28
Month: 4
Minmimum monthly payment $90.35
Principle Paid $15.05
Remaining Balance $4409.3
Month: 5
Minmimum monthly payment $88.55
Principle Paid $14.76
Remaining Balance $4321.11
Month: 6
Minmimum monthly payment $86.78
Principle Paid $14.47
Remaining Balance $4234.68
Month: 7
Minmimum monthly payment $85.04
Principle Paid $14.17
Remaining Balance $4149.99
Month: 8
Minmimum monthly payment $83.34
Principle Paid $13.89
Remaining Balance $4066.99
Month: 9
Minmimum monthly payment $81.67
Principle Paid $13.61
Remaining Balance $3985.66
Month: 10
Minmimum monthly payment $80.04
Principle Paid $13.34
Remaining Balance $3905.94
Month: 11
Minmimum monthly payment $78.44
Principle Paid $13.07
Remaining Balance $3827.82
Month: 12
Minmimum monthly payment $76.87
Principle Paid $12.81
Remaining Balance $3751.27
Month: 13
```

Here is what they have:

```
Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: 4800
Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: .2
Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: .02
Month: 1
Minimum monthly payment: $96.0
Principle paid: $16.0
Remaining balance: $4784.0
Month: 2
Minimum monthly payment: $95.68
Principle paid: $15.95
Remaining balance: $4768.05
Month: 3
Minimum monthly payment: $95.36
Principle paid: $15.89
Remaining balance: $4752.16
Month: 4
Minimum monthly payment: $95.04
Principle paid: $15.84
Remaining balance: $4736.32
Month: 5
Minimum monthly payment: $94.73
Principle paid: $15.79
Remaining balance: $4720.53
Month: 6
Minimum monthly payment: $94.41
Principle paid: $15.73
Remaining balance: $4704.8
Month: 7
Minimum monthly payment: $94.1
Principle paid: $15.69
Remaining balance: $4689.11
Month: 8
Minimum monthly payment: $93.78
Principle paid: $15.63
Remaining balance: $4673.48
Month: 9
Minimum monthly payment: $93.47
Principle paid: $15.58
Remaining balance: $4657.9
Month: 10
Minimum monthly payment: $93.16
Principle paid: $15.53
Remaining balance: $4642.37
Month: 11
Minimum monthly payment: $92.85
Principle paid: $15.48
Remaining balance: $4626.89
Month: 12
Minimum monthly payment: $92.54
Principle paid: $15.43
Remaining balance: $4611.46
RESULT
Total amount paid: $1131.12
Remaining balance: $4611.46
```

Why is my number not the same?

Comment: I've edited your question for better readability, check if the indentation and code blocks are all right

Comment: I had everything from Min_monthly_payment all the way to the end indented by four spaces equally.  I don't know how you reformatted it but I tried again but it just made things worse.

Comment: I've re-edited as per your feedback. Does it look ok now?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the outstanding balance variable in the iteration, because otherwise it will not change.